# Open questions in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, open-problem

I was wondering if there are any really important or widely studied open problems in probability, we all know about the millennium problems list, but no one of those is directly related to probability. I  found some questions like this on the internet but they were all relatively old and with somewhat vague responses. So by making this question I'm hoping to bring it up to date and make kind of a archive of those problems.

Thanks in advance